# How to create a method in controller for the IF condition to call in the view in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am a newbie. I just want to create a method in the controller for the following code to avoid repeating again in the view. How can I write in a short and elegant way in ruby on rails?

```
<% @A = ....... %>
<% @B = ....... %>
<% @C = ....... %>
<% @D = ....... %>
<% @E = ....... %>

<% if (@A || @B || @C) %>
  <label> One: </label>
  <%= ... %>

  <label> Two: </label>
  <%= ... %>
<% end %>

<% if (@A || @B || @C || (@D && @E)) %>
  <label> Three: </label>
  <%= ... %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: so you already have this logic in your view AND in your controller? 
If you only have that in your view, why do you use class variables (`@A` instead of `a`)?

Comment: I just have these in my view. Not in my controller. But my task is to create a method for this in controller and short the code in VIEW.

Comment: If you are every only going to use this logic in the view, I would advise you to put it in the **helper**, not in the controller.

Comment: helper? am a very beginner. any example would help for me to update... Thanks

Comment: and please explain me why Helper is better than controller.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your model is called **`User`** and the code you provided is placed in **"app/views/users/show.html.erb"**

I suggest the following refactoring:
(you need to replace `A,B,C,D and E` with the appropriate logic and rename the methods to something more meaningful)

```
# in "app/helpers/users_helper.rb"
module UsersHelper
  def isABC
    return A || B || C
  end

  def isDandE
    return D && E
  end
end

# in "app/views/users/show.html.erb
<% if (isABC) %>
  <label> One: </label>
  <%= ... %>

  <label> Two: </label>
  <%= ... %>
<% end %>

<% if (isABC || isDandE) %>
  <label> Three: </label>
  <%= ... %>
<% end %>
```

---

You can read up on Rails helpers here: http://paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/49-using-helper-methods-in-ruby-on-rails

Basically the reponsibility of a controller is to accept incoming web requests, fetch the neccessary data (`Model`) and call the appropriate `View` for rendering.

Rails has `Helpers` that can be called from your `Views`. The idiom is that you put any *advanced logic* used in the view into the `Helper`

Comment: if i dont have a USERS model... is it possible to create a helper file by controller rather than model?

Comment: You didn't give a name for your controller/model/view, so I just assumed `User`. Replace it with whatever suits your needs

Comment: i just had epc_admins_controller.rb. I don't have a model for this and all the variables has association with some other models. When i do the same as you told, i got the association failed.....

Comment: That is because you can not just copy my code. You will have to adjust it to your situation, i.e. you need to change the names to match your controller / view names. What's the name of your views (the path)?

Comment: thanks.. and i am not copied. my view folder name is epc_admins and the exact view file name is _recomendations.html.erb(partial called in index file)

Comment: then create a helper in `app/helpers/epc_admins_helper` and replace the name `UsersHelper` in my example with `EPCAdminsHelper` (refer your controller name for the correct way to write it).

Comment: I created the epc_admins_helper only and not UsersHelper

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22593/discussion-between-yas4891-and-vinay)